# Probability of working machine with $3$ components

Tags: probability

I have this task to do:

> A machine is composed of $3$ components, which function independently of
>   each other with probabilities $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$, respectively. Calculate the probability that the machine works when
>
> - the machine only works when all the components are working,
> - the machine works when at least one of the components works.

Since I don't know what are the probabilities $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$, I assume I would have to work on them, and not real numbers.

For the first case, I think it should be $p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot p_3$.

When it comes to the second one, I'm confused. Should it be $1 - p_1 \cdot p_2$? It makes sense to me, but why wouldn't it be $1 - p_2 \cdot p_3$? Maybe I should include all of them? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please, tell me if my first assumption is correct as well!

Comment: I think you are right on the first one, for the second one, what is the probability that none of the components work?

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct.  Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks, I didnt know how to edit it correctly, this will clear things up! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first part of the question is correct
$$
P(\text{the machine works})=p_1p_2p_3.
$$
The answer to the second part of the question can be obtained in the following way
$$
P(\text{the machine works})=1-P(\text{the machine does not work}).
$$
If the machine does not work, it means that all of the components failed. The probabability that a component fails is equal to $1-p_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. Using the independence,
$$
P(\text{the machine does not work})=(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3).
$$
Hence,
$$
P(\text{the machine works})=1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3).
$$

Comment: thank you, I'm halfway to understanding it I think. So if there was a case that the machine works only if at least two components are working, I should calculate it like P(the machine works) = 1 - (1-p1p2)(1-p2p3)(1-p1p3)? I really want to make sure I understand it, hope it's good!

Comment: @Pauline Sometimes it is much easier to calculate the probability $P(A^c)$ of the complement of an event than the probability $P(A)$ of the event itself. That's what I used in my answer. I think it is easier to calculate the probability directly in the situation when the machine works when at least two components work. Then we obtain the following answer: p_1p_2p_3+(1-p_1)p_2p_3+p_1(1-p_2)p_3+p_1p_2(1-p_3).